# Cookie that dies when you leave the page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, cookies

Is it somehow possible (using Laravel5.2/PHP or/and JS/jQuery) to set cookie that expires when user leaves a certain page or certain domain?

Comment: Sure, it's called a session cookie, and it dies when the user closes the browser.

Comment: If I recall correctly that's the default when you don't set an expiration date. How exactly do you currently set the *do not expire on close* kind of cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**window.onclose** method can be called to delete cookies

Basically cookie is saved in client's machine. But if you want to delete cookie by closing window use a session ($_SESSION) cookie. It will automatically expire on window close.

In your case it will be better to use window.onclose and find the specific page by getting Laravel URL class and delete the cookie

Comment: Relying in some client-side code to actively remove a cookie is an accident waiting to happen, esp. when you can just configure a cookie to disappear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookies to expire when the session end (a.k.a when the user closes the browser), also you have the option to programatically delete the cookies inside Laravel, which if u want can also be triggered by making your own ajax call to your own controller.

You can find the expire on close option inside the `config\session.php`